# Making Http Get And Post Request

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, http

i am new to android programming and i am trying to develop an app that calls this web services, passes the values and gets a return in the form of an xml but everytime a make a request i get a return as the data entry not valid. I tried doing through Http get And Post but both are not wrking. The Url is as follows,

http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/webservices/hiscentral.asmx?op=GetSeriesCatalogForBox2

and the code is,

```
HttpGet:

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener   
{
 String xml=null;
 String responseBody;
 String text = null;
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    b.setClickable(false);
    new LongRunningGetIO().execute();
}

private class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> 
{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {

try 
         {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
         HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
         HttpGet httpGet = new     HttpGet("http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/webservices/hiscentral.asmx/GetSeriesCatalogForBox2?xmin=-100 &xmax=-90 &ymin=40 &ymax=55 &conceptKeyword=precipitation &beginDate=1/1/2009&endDate=1/1/2010 HTTP/1.1");
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
          HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
          text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
         } 

         catch (Exception e) 
         {
             return e.getLocalizedMessage();
         }
         return text;
    }   



     catch (ClientProtocolException e)
                     {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     } 
                     catch (IOException e)
                     {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }

                 } 
             catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
             {
              e.printStackTrace();
              }
             return responseBody;
    }
      protected void onPostExecute(String results) 
                    {
                        if (results!=null) 
                        {
                            EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit);
                            et.setText(results);
                        }
                        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
                        b.setClickable(true);
                    }
                }
            }
```

and the HttpPost is,

```
HttpPost
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener   
{
String xml=null;
String responseBody;
String text = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
b.setClickable(false);
new LongRunningGetIO().execute();
}

private class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> 
{


@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
{
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
         String Url = "http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/webservices/hiscentral.asmx?op=GetSeriesCatalogForBox2";
         if(!Url.endsWith("?"))
         {
                Url += "?";
         }
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url); 
             // Add data   

             List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);   
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xmin", "-100"));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xmax", "-90"));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ymin", "40"));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ymax", "55"));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("networkIDs", ""));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("conceptKeyword", "precipitation"));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("beginDate", "1/1/2009"));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("endDate", "1/1/2010"));
             try 
             {         
                      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                     //  Log.d("myapp", "works till here. 2"); 
                      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                      responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                     //    Log.d("myapp", "response " + response.getEntity());
                     // HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                      //   xml = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
                     } 
                     catch (Exception e) 
                     {
                         return e.getLocalizedMessage();
                     }
             return responseBody;
    }

                     protected void onPostExecute(String results) 
                    {
                        if (results!=null) 
                        {
                            EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit);
                            et.setText(results);
                        }
                        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
                        b.setClickable(true);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please Help !!
Thanx in adnvance..

Comment: What you are trying to download? JSON XML or a BITMAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You re missing **networkIDs** parameter in HttpGet so try this:

```
    http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/webservices/hiscentral.asmx/GetSeriesCatalogForBox2?xmin=-100&xmax=-90&ymin=40&ymax=55&conceptKeyword=precipitation&
networkIDs=YOUR_NETWORK_IDS&beginDate=1/1/2009&endDate=1/1/2010
```

instead of

```
    http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/webservices/hiscentral.asmx/GetSeriesCatalogForBox2?xmin=-100&xmax=-90&ymin=40&ymax=55&
conceptKeyword=precipitation&beginDate=1/1/2009&endDate=1/1/2010%20HTTP/1.1
```

and In  **HttpPost** change your url as:

```
String Url = "http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/webservices/hiscentral.asmx/GetSeriesCatalogForBox2";
```

Comment: thanx a lot.. the HttpPost is working fine now...
regarding the HttpGet request, the Network ID was mentioned as optional... so have any idea why that is not working ?

Comment: yes parameter value is optional not parameter so if you u do't want to pass networkids then use this `http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/webservices/hiscentral.asmx/GetSeriesCatalogForBox2?xmin=-100&xmax=-90&ymin=40&ymax=55&conceptKeyword=precipitation&
networkIDs=&beginDate=1/1/2009&endDate=1/1/2010`

Comment: ahhhh thanx a lot :)
and bro one more thing if u can help me,
the output is in form of an xml.. if i need to parse it to get only specific values, as in when i pass the parameter i get something like 25 different values out of which i want just 2 values.. so u have any link of tutorail for tht? coz the one i am using is having a bug problem

Comment: if u can then u cud u gimme ur mail id so tht i can send u the xml and be specific of what i am asking.. will be of great help bro !!

Comment: thanx bro.. have mailed u the details